# URL Rewriting - removing the entire page name

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

Currently I have a rewrite rule in my web.config that removes the ".aspx" page extension.

I want to rewrite my URL to remove the whole page name "page1.aspx" so my URL will show as "www.mysite.com/folder/" and not "www.mysite.com/folder/page1"

My rewrite code in the web.config I currently use is the following :

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="Redirect to clean URL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^([._0-9a-z-/]+).aspx$" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="RewriteASPX" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

What do I need to add or edit to my current rules to get the results I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quickly testing it on regex101.com, does this work?

```
<match url="^([._0-9a-z-/]+)/(.+).aspx$" ignoreCase="true" />
```

and

```
<action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}/" />
```

Adding the "/(.+)" makes sure the last word before aspx gets removed from the first match (R:0). R:1 will contain that word: "page1" while R:0 will contain:"www.mysite.com/folder".